# How to display different content on different title page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress template and I am trying to display different content on  different categories pages:

```
single_cat_title('');
```

How do I use this in a php template? When I have a category (e.g. `CATEGORY-1`) I need to display different content than another category (e.g. `CATEGORY-2`).

```
if single_cat_title(''); is a CATEGORY-1 then display CONTENT-1 else DISPLAY CONTENT-1
```

Comment: Read about [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)/[else](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)/[switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements? Have you *attempted* anything yourself?

Comment: I'd suggest a VERY basic beginners intro to PHP first. **if single_cat_title(''); is a CATEGORY-1 then display CONTENT-1 else DISPLAY CONTENT-1 ** is no way anything PHP-ish.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions.

1. You could make use of [category templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates). The idea behind them is that you create a separate php file for each category. You can use names like `category-1.php`, `category-2.php` etc. for category IDs or `category-name.php`, `category-other-name.php` etc. for category names.
   To avoid writing the same pieces of code in each of those files, you should put the shared code in another file or multiple files (e.g. shared.php or, even better, header.php, footer.php and so on). You can wrap the shared code in [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) for more control. Then include the shared file(s) in all category templates and call the functions:

   ```
   include('shared.php'); // including the shared code
   show_header(); // our function for displaying header
   /*
   * do category-specific stuff
   */
   show_footer(); // our function for displaying footer
   ```
2. You can use a single category template (`category.php` by default), check what is the current category and perform different actions for different categories. There is a special function for checking the category, called [is_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category). It would look like this:

   ```
   //(...) some header code here

   if(is_category('some_category')) {
           // perform specific actions
   }
   else if(is_category('other_category')) {
           // perform specific actions
   }
   else {
           // some unknown category. perform specific actions
   }

   // (...) some footer code here
   ```